# How do I delete an element from a list if the userinput is in the list?

Tags: python, list, user-input

If i have a list like this:

```
colourlist = [a,b,c,d]
```

and have a userinput to input any letters:

```
userinput = input("Enter a letter: ")
```

is it possible to make it so that if the user inputs the letter "a", how do i make it delete from the list automatically so the list becomes:

```
colourlist = [b,c,d]
```

Edit: I want it to remove it from the list automatically instead of  if a == a, colourlist.remove [a], I want it to be like if a in colourlist, then it will delete that element from the list

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please add what have you tried doing so far and what have you found out with some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the user input to a variable and then `remove()` that value.

```
userinput = input("Enter a letter: ")
colourlist.remove(userinput)
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
try:
    colourlist.remove(input("Enter a letter: "))
except ValueError:
    print('Input not in list')
```

This will try to remove the input from the list and if it is not in the list it says `Input not in list`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `remove` with a `try-except` block. It'll throw error if the input is not in the list.

```
x= list('abcd')
u_in = input()
try:
  x.remove(u_in)
except:
  None
```